# How to use structured data for service categories?

Tags: schema.org, microdata

So I am trying to understand this confusing documentation from schema.org and want to fix my structured data. Lets say I offer music recording and production services. So to show through html:

example without Structured data

> ```
> <ul>
> // this is the main
>
> <h1>Music Recording and Production</h1>
>
> // these are subcategories
>
> <li>voice recording</li>
> <li>musical instrument recording </li>
> <li>mixing and mastering tracks</li>
> <li>blah blah</li>
> <li>blah blah</li>
> <li>blah blah</li> 
> </ul>
> ```

So if i were to inject structured data would it be:

```
 <ul>
    <h1 itemtype itemscope="https://schema.org/Service">We offer **Music Recording and Production**</h1>
    <li itemprop="hasOfferCatalog">voice recording</li>
    <li itemprop="hasOfferCatalog">musical instrument recording </li>
    <li itemprop="hasOfferCatalog">mixing and mastering tracks</li>
    <li itemprop="hasOfferCatalog">blah blah</li>
    <li itemprop="hasOfferCatalog">blah blah</li>
    <li itemprop="hasOfferCatalog">blah blah</li> 
    </ul>
```

and then if those subcategories had some description, what itemprop would they eat?

Comment: You can’t have a `h1` in a `ul`.

Comment: Do you mean the example on [`hasOfferCatalog`](http://schema.org/hasOfferCatalog)? What is confusing about it?

Comment: unor - with a little css i can turn h1 inside ul to whatever i want. I already found my solution thank you. this was not running well on webmaster testing tools. i should've been using nested elements like this as google says:

Comment: a sample is at the bottom of this page: https://schema.org/Service

Comment: It doesn’t matter how you style the `h1`. Having a `h1` in `ul` is not allowed in HTML.

Comment: If you have found a solution, please post it as an answer (and accept it).

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic because you indicate in the comments that you found a solution, however you never posted the solution as an answer.